# Adding additional rows to dataframe where date is the index

Tags: python, dataframe

Im trying to add additional rows to a data frame where the index is DateTime and am not sure how to go about doing this

```
AAPL=yf.download('AAPL')
AAPL=AAPL['Adj Close']
AAPL.loc[len(AAPL.index)]=['2021-12-04',0]
```

This is the error message i recieved

```
TypeError: cannot insert DatetimeArray with incompatible label
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had better first convert your date `string` to a `datetime` object type in pandas and then do whatever you want.
This is your method:

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf

AAPL = yf.download('AAPL')
AAPL = AAPL['Adj Close']
AAPL.loc[pd.to_datetime('2021-12-04')] = 0
# This is also acceptable
# AAPL.loc['2021-12-04'] = 0
print(AAPL)
```

And Here is my method to cope with this:

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf

AAPL = yf.download('AAPL')
AAPL = AAPL[['Adj Close']]
AAPL = AAPL.append(pd.DataFrame(0, index=[pd.to_datetime('2021-12-04')], columns=AAPL.columns))
print(AAPL)
```

Output

```
             Adj Close
1980-12-12    0.100453
1980-12-15    0.095213
1980-12-16    0.088224
1980-12-17    0.090408
1980-12-18    0.093029
...                ...
2021-12-30  178.199997
2021-12-31  177.570007
2022-01-03  182.009995
2022-01-04  179.699997
2021-12-04    0.000000
```